# 5k ms Planning time for 2k rows table

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a table that has 44 columns and slightly less than 2000 rows. Also, the data are all text or integers. Texts don't go longer than a few characters. Table size is about 1900kb. All my other tables' planning time is less than 10ms.

```
explain analyze select * from my_table_1 where my_table_1_primary_key=1
```

query as simple as this yields
planning time: 2000~6000ms
execution time: 0.6~2ms

My suspect for the problem is

1. pg_catalog.pg_statistic being 588MB for unknown reason. => the grand sum of all my tables is less than 10 MB of data.
2. I do very frequent update for `my_table_1`. About 50 updates every 2 minutes, each update updating 5 columns of corresponding single rows.
3. I have 6 unique columns which auto generates 7 indexes in total. (including single column primary key)

Any ideas on my situation?

Comment: If you are mostly interested in fixing the problem (rather than assigning blame for it), I would start by doing VACUUM FULL followed by VACUUM ANALYZE on both my_table_1 and pg_statistic and see if that takes care of it.  Assuming you can put up with the lock time.

Comment: thnx for the advice. I tried myariads of solutions and it turns out vendor specific problem. Direct connection to DB had explain result to be 2ms planing time, but connection from a vendor dashboard was the issue.